# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Why this error is showing when, I had already defined it.

This is my code:

```js
  document,onkeydown =  function reload(e){
    var re = e.keyCode;

    console.log("key " + e.keyCode);
    console.log("test");

    if (re==32) {
      reload();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

1. replace `document,onkeydown` with `document.onkeydown`
2. you don’t have to set a name for the function while using event, so you will need to replace `function reload(e){` with `function(e){`